# how to optimize the below MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, query-optimization, collation

the below query it scans more rows while the table has an index on it but  not using that index for that column.

Query;

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  st_aepsrequest_log 
WHERE 
  `snd_transno` IN (
    SELECT 
      pwcashout_transno 
    FROM 
      st_aeps_transaction_master a 
    WHERE 
      a.`entry_date` >= '2022-09:29 13:00:00' 
      AND a.entry_date <= '2022-09-29 13:30:00'
  )
```

row scans;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: st_aepsrequest_log
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 7355201
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: a
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: snd_unique,pwaeps_transno,entry_date
          key: snd_unique
      key_len: 92
          ref: func
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

table structure;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: st_aepsrequest_log
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `st_aepsrequest_log` (
  `serno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `db_serno` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `brand` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `counter_code` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `transno` char(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `snd_transno` char(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `latlog` char(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `trans_mode` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `amount` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `intime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `outtime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_agent` text NOT NULL,
  `remote_ip` text NOT NULL,
  `request` text NOT NULL,
  `response` text NOT NULL,
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serno`),
  KEY `sndtransno` (`snd_transno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16912804 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: st_aeps_transaction_master
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `st_aeps_transaction_master` (
  `serno` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `entry_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `mode_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `db_serno` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `merchant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `service_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `merchant_channel` enum('RETAIL','B2C') DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchant_users_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `provider_user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `merchant_transno` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `pwcashout_transno` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `rrn` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pw_stan` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `provider_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `service_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bank_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `amount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `total_comm` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `provider_comm` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gst` enum('INCLUSIVE','EXCLUSIVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'INCLUSIVE',
  `gst_value` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `aadhar_no` char(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `aeps_identifier` char(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `provider_rate_mode` enum('PERCENT','AMOUNT','CUSTOM') DEFAULT 'PERCENT',
  `device_info` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `device` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_serno` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `client_ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `refund_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `requery_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `provider_response_message` text,
  `provider_response_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `response` text NOT NULL,
  `trans_settle_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `trans_settle_datetime` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `trans_settle_status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `status` enum('INITIATED','SUCCESS','FAILED') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`serno`),
  UNIQUE KEY `snd_unique` (`pwcashout_transno`),
  KEY `pwaeps_transno` (`pwcashout_transno`),
  KEY `merchant_transno` (`merchant_transno`),
  KEY `entry_date` (`entry_date`),
  KEY `provider_id` (`provider_id`),
  KEY `trans_settle_datetime` (`trans_settle_datetime`),
  KEY `idx_ent_merc` (`merchant_users_id`,`entry_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=87032220 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

is there any way to optimize the above query?

i have added the format of the databases

dfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfsdfdsfdsfdsf
fdshfjsdhjkfhkjdshkfhsjkdfhkdfjhdsjhfgdhjgfjhdjfhgdshjfgjdsf

Comment: you need only one key for pwcashout_transno

Comment: yeah with that date time

Comment: no not for that query, but as you need unique that shoud stay

Comment: but when we are at it why do you have pwcashout_transno uniuqe and ser_no as primary key also unique

Comment: it's from application side database

Comment: I'm don't have not any clue about it .. can you  please give me the soln

Comment: When you say `SHOW CREATE TABLE st_aeps_transaction_master` the output ends with something like `) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1748 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Please [edit] your question to show us those lines from both your tables. Why? if the tables have different collations your `IN()` clause will slow down.

Comment: yeah sure let me share

Comment: in can't replicate your problem see https://dbfiddle.uk/BKcFsKq0  also you can force mysql to use a index https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: i have shared the format for the table one is utf8 and another is latin1 @O.Jones

Comment: but it seems the Latin1 and uttf8 have problem

Comment: Yes, comparing strings of different collations spoils the use of an index. It's not only latin1 and utf8, it's any different collation, even different collations for the same character set. Is it on purpose that your tables use different character sets and collations? I would recommend making them the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character sets and collations are baked into indexes on columns with data types like the `CHAR(30)` you use for `st_aepsrequest_log.snd_transno` and `st_aeps_transaction_master.pwcashout_transno`. So, like @BillKarwin mentioned, if the character sets and collations vary it defeats the use of indexes.

Now, it looks like your subquery `SELECT pwcashout_transno ...` produces a modest number of rows in its result set.  And, the character set for `st_aepsrequest_log.snd_transno` is latin1.  So if you [convert the output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#cast-character-set-conversions) of the subquery to latin1, it should be possible for your `IN()` clause to use the index on that column. `SELECT CONVERT(pwcashout_transno USING latin1)` should do the trick.  Try this version of your query:

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  st_aepsrequest_log 
WHERE 
  `snd_transno` IN (
    SELECT 
      CONVERT(pwcashout_transno USING latin1) 
    FROM 
      st_aeps_transaction_master a 
    WHERE 
      a.`entry_date` >= '2022-09:29 13:00:00' 
      AND a.entry_date <= '2022-09-29 13:30:00'
  )
```

But this is a bit of a hack. It's always better when doing your table design to make the character sets and collations of `CHAR()` and `VARCHAR()` columns match. This is especially true if you JOIN on them or use them on `IN()`  or `=` clauses.

Of course, redefining the tables may not be possible for your application.

Answer (score 1):

If the query from OJones does not work, then avoid `IN ( SELECT ... )` by doing this:

```
SELECT  log.*
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  CONVERT(a.pwcashout_transno USING latin1) AS pt
            FROM  st_aeps_transaction_master a
            WHERE  a.entry_date >= '2022-09:29 13:00:00'
              AND  a.entry_date  < '2022-09-29 13:00:00'
                                    + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  st_aepsrequest_log AS log  ON log.snd_transno = x.pt
```

Then, this index may help:  `INDEX(entry_date, pwcashout_transno)`

Note:  If there could be multiple rows with the same `pwcashout_transno`, then the inner (derived) query may need `DISTINCT`.

Comment: ur both answers work fine thank you guys @Rick James